# Bootstrap-ui datepicker close-on-date-selection

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Technologies: 
AngularJs and Bootstrap-ui

Enviroment:
I use a collabsable filter section which is controlled by "FilterCtrl". Each input element in the filter is controlled by a nested controller like "TypeaheadCtrl" or "DatepickerCtrl". The ng-models of each one are bound with "$parent.field" in FilterCtrl.

Problem: 
Datepicker works fine, exept, and this is the issue, it does not close. According to the default settings (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), the datepicker should close on select a date. It does not. Even if I click on the button-bar's "Close" button it does not. If the focus changes, it does close.

HTML:

```
<div class="" ng-controller="FilterCtrl">
  <a class="black bold nodecoration" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" role="button">Filter</a>
<!-- Filter -->
  <div class="bckgrnd-lgrey bordered max-width" collapse="isCollapsed" id="findenFilter">
    <div class="nobreak" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
      <label>Suchbegriff:
        <input ng-model="$parent.searchText" placeholder="z.B. Rock" type="text" typeahead="prediction for prediction in predictions | filter:$viewValue |limitTo:8"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="nobreak" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
      <label>Datum:
        <input class="" close-text="Close" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="status.opened" ng-click="open()" ng-model="$parent.selectedDate" show-weeks="false" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="nobreak">
      <label>Land: </label>
    </div>

    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="printValues()">log values</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:
DatepickerCtrl:

```
angular.module('tbdApp')
  .controller('DatepickerCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.selectedDate = new Date();
    };
    $scope.clear = function() {
      $scope.selectedDate = null;
    };
    $scope.open = function($event) {
      $scope.status.opened = true;
    };


    $scope.status = {
      opened: false
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd.MM.yyyy', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    $scope.today();
  });
```

FilterCtrl:

```
angular.module('tbdApp')
  .controller('FilterCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
    $scope.selectedDate = null;
    $scope.searchText = null;
    $scope.printValues = function () {
      console.log("collapsed: " + $scope.isCollapsed);
      console.log("selectedDate: " + $scope.selectedDate);
      console.log("searchText: " + $scope.searchText);
    }
  });
```

I didnt found anyone who had a similar problem. I suppose it could be a scope issue but I have no idea what excactly the issue could be.

Comment: I cannot post more than two links :')

So heres the last part:
"close()" in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepicker/popup.html should be called when I click on "Close". https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L779

Or when I select a date, it should call https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L706

Comment: Try to create an example in plunkr with your code. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Ok I got it. Its incredible ugly but works as well as the original version - a bit but not 100%.

Enjoy: http://plnkr.co/edit/wxNULyM3TVZ03oDLSnce?p=preview

PS: Collabse does not work in plunkr example. But its not necessary to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your plunkr example, the issue I identified is in the event on your input. Instead of

```
ng-click="open()"
```

do

```
ng-focus="open()"
```

This happens due to the fact that after you select the date, angularjs tries to move the click event into the input box. Not sure why, but this is the behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves my problem, but generates another. It now closes the datepicker correctly with "close" button and with on-select-close, but the focus after closing is on the inputbox and makes it inpossible to trigger the event a second time without clicking somewhere and then again on the inputbox. Do you have a smart and flexible solution for this problem? There's the problem and I dont want to change foreign code (migration horror) https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L781

Comment: Well, if you look at the demo they provide here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for datepicker, the behavior you describe is the default one. I presume without changing the library code, you can try to watch the model value which will be changed by the date selection and then focus on some other element. However, in my experience I never needed to remove the focus from input after date selection.

Comment: Faced the same issue today. Watching the model value and calling `blur()` on the target input wasn't an option for me because **toggling the months also triggers focus loosing** and datepicker just closes itself. After some investigation I found that in case of autoClose option present `scope.$emit('hidePicker');` is being executed, so I could catch it on my controller and blur the input with `$scope.$on('hidePicker', function () { targetElement.blur() }`. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Smart and flexible solution: check the $event.target in open() method.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-datepicker" ng-click="datePickers.open(0, $event)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="date_min" uib-datepicker-popup is-open="datePickers.opened[0]"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
<div class="my-datepicker" ng-click="datePickers.open(1, $event)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="date_max" uib-datepicker-popup is-open="datePickers.opened[1]"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.datePickers = {
    opened: [false, false],

    open: function (i, e) {
        if (!$(e.toElement).parent().hasClass('my-datepicker')) return;
        this.opened[i] = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.